# Login Function Using Entity framework c# winforms Entity framework 4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am using c# and winforms 4.0 to create a lo gin form using entity framework. Question is is my logic right. I am just a we bit worried about the return if it doesn't find a record i add a blank return record is that the correct way using entity framework to return a empty record as I want to pass the information found on the log in screen to the main form.

```
public NaviHrUsers  ValidateUser(string username,string password)
         {

             try{
                 NaviHrUsers currentUser = naviEntities.NaviHrUsers.FirstOrDefault(r => r.login == username);

                 if (currentUser != null)
                 {
                     return currentUser;
                 }

                 else
                 {
                     NaviHrUsers nu = new NaviHrUsers();
                     nu.login = "";
                     nu.password = "";
                     nu.last_login = Convert.ToDateTime("1900/01/01");
                     nu.last_time = "";
                     nu.password_last_changed = Convert.ToDateTime("1900/01/01");
                     return nu;
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("ValidateUser failed.", ex);
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to return a blank record.  Instead, you want to return null.  Also, if you look at Microsoft's Forms Auth in Asp.Net, Membership.ValidateUser() method returns a bool, which all it does is validate the user, nothing more.  For this scenario, I wouldn't consider returning an empty record a good practice.